# clojure.core/or partial function works well with first argument but not with second

Tags: clojure

(defn divisible [x y] (zero? (rem x y)))

1. ((or (fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5))) 3)
2. ((or (fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5))) 5)

the first expression evals to true but not the second one why?

- can some on explain whats going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An expression of the form `(or foo bar)` does not "glue together" two predicates into one compound predicate; it returns `foo` if it is truthy, else `bar`. In your code, `(fn [x] (divisible x 3))` is of course truthy (the only falsey values are `false` and `nil`), so the whole thing is equivalent to

```
((fn [x] (divisible x 3)) 3)
((fn [x] (divisible x 3)) 5)
```

What you want to do is something like

```
(some #(apply % 3) [(fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5)])
(some #(apply % 5) [(fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5)])
              ; ^- here goes the thing being tested
```

In general,

```
(defn or-preds [& preds]
  (fn [& args]
    (some #(apply % args) preds)))

((or-preds (fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5))) 3)
((or-preds (fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5))) 5)
;; or simpler...
((or-preds #(divisible % 3) #(divisible % 5)) 3)
```

Comment: * thanks a lot, I just didn't realize that the first function was returned immediately by or cause it got evaluated as truthy. 
* what I really needed was this #(or (divisible % 3) (divisible % 5))

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that `or` somehow combines the functions that it receives as arguments, but that's not the case. `or` can take any kind of values as arguments and simply returns the first one that is "truthy".

So `(or (fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5)))` returns `(fn [x] (divisible x 3))` (because functions are "not nothing" and thus "truthy").

So when you do `((or (fn [x] (divisible x 3)) (fn [x] (divisible x 5))) something)`, you're really just doing `((fn [x] (divisible x 3)) something)`.